# Unwanted xmlns attribute generated for nodes

Tags: xml, vba

I would like to generate the following XML from VBA.

```
<TokenRequest xmlns:common="http://whatever/common" xmlns="http://whatever/api">
    <common:header>
        <common:requestId>12345</common:requestId>
    </common:header>
    <software>
        <requestId>ABCDE</requestId>
    </software>
</TokenRequest>
```

The issue with my below code is that it generates the xmlns:common attribute also in the common:header node.

So instead of this:

```
<common:header>
```

I get this:

```
<common:header xmlns:common="http://whatever/api">
```

And this is the piece of code I'm using:

```
ns1 = "http://whatever/api"
ns2 = "http://whatever/common"

Set xRequest = New DOMDocument
    
Set xeTokenRequest = xRequest.createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, "TokenRequest", ns1)
xRequest.appendChild xeTokenRequest

Set xeAttrTmp = xRequest.createAttribute("xmlns")
xeAttrTmp.nodeValue = ns1
xeTokenRequest.Attributes.setNamedItem xeAttrTmp

Set xeAttrTmp = xRequest.createAttribute("xmlns:common")
xeAttrTmp.nodeValue = ns2
xeTokenRequest.Attributes.setNamedItem xeAttrTmp

'Create elements
Set xeHeader = xRequest.createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, "common:header", ns1)
xeTokenRequest.appendChild xeHeader

Set xeTmp = xRequest.createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, "common:requestId", ns1)
xeTmp.nodeTypedValue = "12345"
xeHeader.appendChild xeTmp

Set xeSoftware = xRequest.createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, "software", ns1)
xeTokenRequest.appendChild xeSoftware

Set xeTmp = xRequest.createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, "requestId", ns1)
xeTmp.nodeTypedValue = "ABCDE"
xeSoftware.appendChild xeTmp
```

The full XML generated using above code is the following:

```
<TokenRequest xmlns:common="http://whatever/common" xmlns="http://whatever/api">
    <common:header xmlns:common="http://whatever/api">
        <common:requestId>12345</common:requestId>
    </common:header>
    <software>
        <requestId>ABCDE</requestId>
    </software>
</TokenRequest>
```

How can I get rid of that attribute on the node level?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply, have prefixed nodes point to its corresponding namespace (`"http://whatever/common"`) and without prefix nodes point to default namespaces (`"http://whatever/api"`). Recall, a declared namespace prefix overwrites default namespace.

```vb
Set xeHeader = xRequest.createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, "common:header", ns2)

Set xeTmp = xRequest.createNode(NODE_ELEMENT, "common:requestId", ns2)
```

**Output**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<TokenRequest xmlns="http://whatever/api" xmlns:common="http://whatever/common">
    <common:header>
        <common:requestId>12345</common:requestId>
    </common:header>
    <software>
        <requestId>ABCDE</requestId>
    </software>
</TokenRequest>
```